# Sending a structure over a UDP socket interface using python

Tags: python, arrays, structure, pack, unpack

I need to send a structure using a UDP socket. I have done this before in C, Siemens PLC and Mitsubishi PLC. However I am having problems with python because python doesn't really have a structure type with fields. The structure contains a 16 byte header and a N x np.float32 array.  I can make the header no problem using pack.  However I need to append the array of float32. The only solution I see is to write a for loop that packs one float32 at a time and appends it do the header.   This seems terribly inefficient.  In C and even in a PLC I can just copy the array to offset 16 in a buffer then send it.
Is there a better way?